# Destroying energy

Tags: energy-conservation, superconductivity

The experiment is simple You make a capacitor using superconducting plates. You charge said capacitor. You then discharger capacitor through another superconductor. It would seem that you have destroyed energy.

Comment: You have an [LC circuit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462131/lc-circuit-and-the-current/462144). If energy isn't lost as heat, it will be radiated away, not destroyed.

Comment: Hi @Rowan de la Barre, just a tip: it's nicer in general if you explicitly state your question. For example, it may not be clear to someone answering this if he should focus on how this particular case conserves energy, or on how in general, you can never destroy energy

Comment: To clean up this question so that it may be considered for reopening, you need to make it clear what you are asking (by, for instance including _an actual question_ at the end, like "what happened?" or "how is my model wrong?"), and since you're proposing a hypothetical situation, state by what mechanism you believe that energy has been destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

To discharge the capacitor, the superconductor link must be attached to something that is at a lower voltage than the capacitor. Whatever this is, it cannot be part of the superconductor since the whole superconductor is by definition at the same voltage as the capacitor. Once the discharge current from the capacitor leaves the superconductor link then the energy that was stored in the capacitor is dissipated as heat.

Comment: One capacitor leg to the other capacitor leg. So the two plates on the capacitor are made of superconducting material, and the connection to those two plates are made of super conducting material, in the bus bar you put between those two connectors is a super conducting material.